# ul > li line distance make smaller

Tags: html, html-lists

for example :

```
<ul> 
<li>first Line</li>
<li>second Line</li>
</ul>
```

when i give any li size for example 40px it makes output like This

```
First
Line
```

and distance is big for me. i want make smaller distance between first and line output. thanks for help .

---

thanks Guys line-height  helps me Thanks Lot All :)

Comment: Can you show the CSS you're using to set the `li` "size"?

Comment: jsfiddle.net - go there, create a demo, save it, edit the link into your question. A jsFiddle tells much more than any words could. I don't get what you mean by "size for example 40px" and where do you want a smaller distance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ul or parent div is hasn't got enough width to contain both words. Try `overflow` and/or `word-wrap` in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set a `line-height` to `<li>` elements to rule the distance between lines